# Removing a letter before a capital letter

Tags: c#, regex

I have a few names as strings that have an '*x*' before their last name that needs to be removed.

So, for example, '*John xSmith*' needs to come back as '*John Smith*', but not affecting a name like 'Jane x Doe'.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have any code that's close but not quite doing what you want? Show us some code and we can help you make it work.

Comment: if you were to **split** your string into each word, would it always be the last word you need to remove this from?

Comment: Is it a literal `x` or is the x a placeholder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the regular expression `(?<=\s)x(?=[A-Z])` to remove all of the x's followed by a capital letter and after a whitespace.

Comment: you might consider adding a space before the x in the regex.

\sx(?=[A-Z])

Comment: Ah thanks this is a great help and got it working thank you and for all the other replies been really helpful

Answer (score 0):

Does this regEx match your string? ^([a-zA-Z ]+)x([A-Z][a-zA-Z ]+)*$
After, you have just to use the 2 match between parenthesis to rebuild your string without the 'x'

Comment: Not totally right, see [this](http://www.regex101.com/r/qB1cR4). You might consider extending the capture group to: `^([a-zA-Z ]+)x([A-Z][a-zA-Z ]+)*$`

Comment: you're right.Sorry for the error...

Comment: That's okay, don't worry :)

Answer (score 0):

This is not use regex but it will achieve what you are trying to do (including allowing names such as **Jane x Doe**)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string name = "John xSmith";
    var result = new StringBuilder();
    string[] splitString = name.Split(' ');
    foreach (string partName in splitString)
    {
        if (partName.Length > 1 && partName.StartsWith("x"))
        {
            result.Append(partName.Substring(1));
        }
        else
        {
            result.Append(partName);
        }
        result.Append(" ");
    }
    Console.WriteLine(result.ToString().Trim());
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

With `name = "John xSmith"` would produce **John Smith**

With `name = "Jane x Doe"` would produce **Jane x Doe**